# FromHelper with Fluent Validation in ASP.NET Core failed to send back custom validation error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to use a custom rule validation for list of item

In **startup.cs**

```
        services.AddFluentValidation(config =>
        {
            config.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
        });
```

In the controller class

```
    [FormValidator]
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(DocumentUploader model)
    {
        // add to database 
        return FormResult.CreateSuccessResult("Upload Successfull", Url.Action(nameof(Index)));
    }
```

In the validator class

```
 public DocumentUploadInfoValidator()
 {
        RuleFor(arg => arg.Type).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(arg => arg.File).NotNull().Custom((arg, context) => {
            bool isValidFileType = FileTypeHelper.IsValidImageContentType(FileTypeHelper.GetContentType(arg.FileName));
            bool isFileSizeInRange = arg.Length / 1024 <= 200;

            if (!isValidFileType)
            {
                context.AddFailure("Please upload the following file types: .jpeg, .png");
            }
            else if (!isFileSizeInRange)
            {
                context.AddFailure("Oops! The size limit for documents is 200kb. Reduce the file size and try again");
            }
            else if (IsBlurry(arg))
            {
                context.AddFailure("Document is blurred! Please scan a valid copy of the selected document and upload");
            }
        });


}

 public class DocumentUploaderValidator : AbstractValidator<DocumentUploader>
 {
    public DocumentUploaderValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(a => a.Documents).SetValidator(new DocumentUploadInfoValidator());
    }
 }
```

Html Form

```
<form id="submit_document_form" asp-formhelper="true" asp-action="upload" asp-controller="document" asp-area="@Globals.Areas.Dashboard" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input asp-for"Id" class="d-none" hidden />
    @{
    
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Documents.Count(); i++)
         {
             <div class="form-group">
               <label class="form-label" asp for="@documents[i].File">Upload Document</label>
                  <label class="custom-file-wrapper">
                  <input asp-for="@documents[i].File" data-document-file-picker="readurl" type="file" />
                 <span class="file-custom">Choose file...</span>
               </label>
               <span asp-validation-for="@documents[i].File" class="text-danger small"></span>
             </div>
         }
      }
  </form>
```

It works okay but then am not getting back the validation error message instead when i check my console log in the browser i get this error

[image: Browser Console Log Error]

Comment: Showing the Javascript error message isn't hugely helpful. What is actually returned? Show us that. And show us how this validator is being called. In fact, are you even sure it is being called?

Comment: i will add all the necessary information

Comment: That doesn't look like an issue with your ASP.NET API. What happens if you make that request using Swagger?

Comment: I haven't done that yet

Comment: You're still not showing us what the server is returning.

Comment: The problem is that you're asking about backend side validation issue but you provide frontend side error. And we know nothing about your frontend and its integration with backed. Can you put breakpoint inside your custom validator? Does the request enters your validator? What is returned from your API? Please tell us what happens backend side, try to make a request using postman / swagger instead showing us js error from browser console. You can take a look at your network tab first - what's the response?

Comment: @Konrad Kacperczyk It works okay on the backend, i added a break point and stepped through all the validation process and there wasn't any error

Comment: i will a screenshot of the result from postman to the question

Comment: No, don't keep adding screenshots. Give us the *actual text that the server responds with*. You can see this in the browser dev tools in the network tab.

Comment: @DavidG `{"status":4,"validationErrors":[{"propertyName":"Documents[0].File","message":"Document is blurred! Please scan a valid copy of the selected document and upload"}],"isSucceed":false}`

Comment: Everything is okay with your validation code. You have a bug somewhere on fronted side when parsing response.

Comment: yeah the problem could be from `FormHelper`

Comment: You must improve your question with you front-end code! Problably the error is in there.

Comment: @Mårshåll alright i will do that